# How to find all tags without tag-wiki

Tags: support, tag-wiki

How to find all tags without tag-wiki? I want to add some descriptions for rare tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can look for tags missing a tag wiki or excerpt on the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) (updated every week). Some relevant queries:

- [Most common tags with missing wiki/excerpt](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/94917/most-common-tags-with-missing-wiki-excerpt)
- [Most common tags with missing wiki](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104525/most-common-tags-with-missing-wiki)
- [All tags without a wiki excerpt](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81670/all-tags-without-a-wiki-excerpt)
- [Wikiless tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73048/wikiless-tags)
- [Tag Wikis that are Too Short](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/213068/tag-wikis-that-are-too-short)

---

Do keep in mind that it's difficult to write a good tag wiki for a subject you don't know well. Rare concepts should be defined, but **in a way that makes sense to the community**, i.e. to programmers. **Do not copy-paste** from Wikipedia or from a product's web page: they rarely give the *right* amount of information. Unlike Wikipedia, we aren't terribly interested in things like historical details, but more in what this software does, what it interoperates with, etc. Unlike the product vendor, we aren't here to sell the product. The wiki body should usually focus on practical problems that programmers may face: discuss related technologies, link to tutorials, link to commonly-asked questions on SO, etc. Read the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/) [posts](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/).

Answer (score 6):

**Currently there is no way to find tags which don't have a tag-wiki**.

It may not be useful to add this feature because of the following reasons mentioned by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152867/searching-for-popular-tags-without-tag-wikis):

> It would also generate a lot of crap tag wiki suggestions from users who want the badge and can now easily find all the tags without wikis. Users who don't actually know anything about the tag or how it's used will go briefly research it on Google to get a general idea and then suggest a crap wiki that doesn't really explain anything or help anyone use the tag properly. Even worse, they'll get approved because some people reviewing suggesting edits just don't care.
>
> I really don't see any useful purpose for having a way to search for tags without wikis. If you really care about tag wikis, look at the tags on questions that interest you. If you see new tags you haven't noticed before, just skim through them to see how exactly it's being used and whether you know enough to write a wiki for it. This is exactly what I do, especially here on Meta. I'd rather wait for a tag wiki from a legitimate user who cares about the tag wiki, than get a crap one now from someone who saw it in a list.